# Is it possible/ how to perform upsert on a sharded MongoDB cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-update, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I’d like to perform an upsert operation on a sharded MongoDB cluster, but I get the exact same error for every variation I try. When I write this way to a local standalone Mongo, it works perfectly, but on the sharded cluster I get the errors.

My cluster currently has the structure of a unique (obviously) id at the `_id` field, and another (also unique) id at the `itemId` field - which is the sharded key. I’m using Reactive Spring Data, but I’ve managed to restore the same error on the CLI of this sharded Mongo instance.

The error was `Failed to target upsert by query :: could not extract exact shard key`. My queries were variations of this query:

```
db.MyCollection.updateOne({"_id": "a2","itemId": "a2"}, 
{"$set": {"itemId": "a3"}}, 
{upsert: true},
{multi: false})
```

Also when I don’t update the sharded field, the error remains the same:

```
db.MyCollection.updateOne({"_id": "a2","itemId": "a2"}, 
{"$set": {"itemColor": "brown"}}, 
{upsert: true},
{multi: false})
```

`updateMany()` \ `multi: true` variations didn't work as well. This [page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#behavior) wasn't very helpful too.

I’ve read suggestions of adding the `@Sharded` annotation so that Spring will automatically add the sharded key to the filter, but since I did it manually I didn’t find that helpful.

Any reason why this can happen? Or what this error even means?

I’m using version 5.0.

Comment: what mongo version are you using?

Comment: Which version do you run? Starting in MongoDB 4.2, you can update a document's shard key value unless the shard key field is the immutable `_id` field. In MongoDB 4.2 and earlier, a document's shard key field value is immutable.

Comment: I’m using version 5.0

Comment: And I don’t need to modify the shard key’s value, but all of the shard key’s document fields.